# How to combine jQuery in-place editor with $wpdb->update

Tags: jquery, ajax, wpdb

i am trying to use jQuery in-place editor (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/) on WordPress to update certain values of a custom made table in my database.

I am not really skilled with AJAX (first time trying to use it) or MYSQL, that's why I am having difficulties. I will try to explain my problem in the best way possible.

What I want is to change the value of the **column** (telephone) inside the **table** (wp_esn_cardholder). Each row has an unique **ID** (id_cardholder).

I can smoothly run the jQuery in-place js inside the page, calling for "save.php"

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".editable").editInPlace({
      url: "http://example.com/save.php",
    });
  });
</script>
```

With save.php I try to update the value, using the following code

```
<?php
global $wpdb; 

$update_value = $_POST['update_value'];
$element_id = $_POST['element_id'];
$original = $_POST['original_html'];

$table = 'esn_cardholder';
$row_id = $_POST['element_id'];

$data_array = array('telephone' => $_POST['update_value']);
$where_array = array('id_cardholder' => $row_id);
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix . $table, $data_array, $where_array )
?>
```

Using Firebug's console, I can see that the following passes through:

```
Parameters application/x-www-form-urlencoded
element_id  278
original_html   old-number
original_value  old-number
update_value    new-number

Source update_value=new-number&element_id=278&original_html=old-number&original_value=old-number
```

The thing won't update the database, and I obviously don't know why. I know that I should sanitize the query but I can think about that once it works :).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use [WordPress' built-in AJAX functionality](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

I had to load WordPress in order to use the wpdb function.
How silly :p.

To do so:

```
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
```

And then finally:

```
global $wpdb;
```